# Select specific data in JSON output

Tags: json, angularjs

I've created a function that does a http request and then saves some data from the JSON output.

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

  'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
  // Search for release dates using the ID.
  var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
  var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
  var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
  var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
  var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
  var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

  $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      if (status == 200) {
          // $scope.movieListID = data.results;
          $scope.movieListID = data;
          console.log($scope.movieListID);

          createMovie.create({
            title: $scope.movieListID.original_title,
            release_date: $scope.movieListID.release_date,
            image: $scope.movieListID.poster_path
          }).then(init);

      } else {
          console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
      }
    })
};
```

This function saves the title, release date en posterpath and that works fine. The problem is that it only saves one `release_date` while the JSON output has a lot more, but I don't know how to acces that.

[This is a example of the JSON output I request](http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=&append_to_response=releases&callback=angular.callbacks._1)

It has a `release_date`, which I save now, but it also has more information,

```
releases":{
  "countries":[
    {"certification":"","iso_3166_1":"GB","primary":true,"release_date":"2015-10-26"},
    {"certification":"","iso_3166_1":"US","primary":false,"release_date":"2015-11-06"},
    {"certification":"","iso_3166_1":"NL","primary":false,"release_date":"2015-11-05"},
    {"certification":"","iso_3166_1":"BR","primary":false,"release_date":"2015-11-05"},
    {"certification":"","iso_3166_1":"SE","primary":false,"release_date":"2015-11-04"},
    {"certification":"","iso_3166_1":"IE","primary":false,"release_date":"2015-10-26"},
```

How would I go about saving the release date for the NL release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate through the countries array, and check if the country code matches the one you wish to retrieve. For your example with 'NL':

```
var releaseNL;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.movieList.releases.countries.length; i++) {
    var release = $scope.movieList.releases.countries[i];        
    if (release['iso_3166_1'] == 'NL') {
        releaseNL = release;
    }
}
```

This is just one of many ways to do this (e.g. you could use `angular.forEach`, wrap it inside a function, etc.), but this should give you an idea.

**Remark:** I noticed you have been asking a lot of very basic questions today, which you could easily answer yourself with a bit more research. E.g. this question is not even AngularJS related, but just a simple JavaScript task. So maybe try to show a bit more initiative next time! ;)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. You are correct to point on the basic questions. It's just that I know it's small things, but I don't know how to resolve them (like this one, I thought it was a Angluar/JSON aspect while it has a JS solution). That's why I thought to ask the small questions here. I learn the best through example.

Comment: No worries! Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yea had to adjust some small things but I'm getting the NL release dates now. But now I'm encountering a small problem when the NL release date isn't provided. I need to fall back on the orignal release date. Going to see if I can think of a fix. I'm thinking a if/else statement.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right path, happy coding!